# C++ sum values from textfile in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, text-files

```
cout<<"Enter the date(Format eg. 8oct16   , enter 1 to Main Menu):";
cin>>dateChoice;
if(dateChoice == "1")
{ displaymainmenu(); return;} 

string samequantityitemName;
int samequantity =0;

for(int i=0;std::getline(myfile,myline);i++) 
{
    if(sp[i].datepurchased == dateChoice) // let say i input 9oct16 , retrieve all info that date = 9oct16
    {   

        cout<<sp[i].itemdesc<<sp[i].quantitypurchased<<endl; // this should print all values that date = 9oct16

             for(int j=0;std::getline(myfile,myline);j++)
            {
                if(sp[i].itemdesc == sp[j+1].itemdesc) // check every line if item desc is the same
                    {
                        samequantity = sp[i].quantitypurchased; 
                        samequantity +=sp[j+1].quantitypurchased; //adding all quantitypurchased;
                        samequantityitemName = sp[i].itemdesc;
                    } // end of if

            } // end of the 2nd for loop

            cout<<samequantity<<"    "<<samequantityitemName<<endl; // **DOESN"T WORK** //


    } // end of if statement for user input
} // end of main for loop
```

Basically I have a textfile that looks like this:

**itemid : itemdesc : unitprice : quantitypurchased : datepurchased**

```
22:blueberries:3:9:9oct16
11:apples:8:7:9oct16
16:melon:9:10:9oct16
17:melon:9:11:9oct16
18:melon:9:12:9oct16
19:melon:9:13:9oct16
67:pineapple:123:12:10oct16
44:po:9:9:10oct16
63:juicy:11:11:10oct16
5:starfruit:6:2:10oct16
5:kiwi:6:2:16oct16
```

I am trying to get this output ( when datepurchased is 9oct16) :

```
blueberries 9
appples 7
melon 46
```

But the output I get is :

```
blueberries 9
```

I am trying to display all the item description and quantity purchased of a specific date input by user . and for duplicate item , I will add up the quantity and only print a single line of the duplicated item with the totaled quantity purchased. What have I go wrong here? is my login flow in the wrong direction?

The code is too long to post for `sp` but for example `sp[1].itemdesc` gives me itemdesc ( **blueberries** ) from first line of the textfile.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It should be a pleasure to read.

Comment: Hi sorry if its abit tough for u to read , I try my best to adjust it and place it neatly.

Comment: inner loop getline reads all lines from file that prevents outer loop getline and output line from seeing them. Redesigning whole code to singel loop with only one getline could help. But I still don't understand where you are supposed to actually parse the content of file after reading it with getline

Comment: what objects does the array sp[] contain ?

Comment: Your code doesn't use `myline`.

Comment: I use the get line  to run my loops according to the number of lines in the textfile , all the content of the file already being retrieved from the a struct declaration I have wrote and already separate them by : somewhere else so I can access them here .

Comment: sp contains the text from the textile that is already separated by " : " , for example sp.itemdesc contains the item description ( blueberries ) .

Comment: @forgivenprog33442 That's bizarre. Why not just loop over your stored data, `sp`?

Comment: @Melpomene sp is not stored is I just use it to retrieve text from textfile

Comment: use `map` to save the key-value pairs, and `string stream` to read the data from the file.

Comment: @UrielEli is there any other way? I tried map before the problem is I need 2 keys but not all the time I need 2 keys ( date , itemdesc )